# Adding record to database includes several photos

Tags: c#, sql-server, file-upload

I have an admin panel that belongs to a news web site in C#. Every record(news) must have one or more photos. Photos will be shown in a slider. So i don't know that how much photos user will upload.  I have two tables in my database, Pics(PicID, NewsID, PicName, PicOrder) and News(NewsID, NewsHeader, NewsContent). I can add news header and news content into News table. But I dont know how to add my pictures and my pictures' names into Pics Table. FileUpload control is useful but i don't know how much photo will be uploaded.

```
string path= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GUNABConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(path);

    SqlCommand[] cmd = new SqlCommand[1];
    string query= "Insert into News (NewsHeader, NewsContent) values (@NewsHeader, @NewsContent)";
    cmd[0] = new SqlCommand();
    cmd[0].CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd[0].Parameters.Add("@NewsHeader", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = TextBox1.Text;
    cmd[0].Parameters.Add("@NewsContent", SqlDbType.VarChar, 8000).Value = TextBox2.Text;

    cmd[0].CommandText = query;

    if (new dab().execute(cmd) == true)
    {
        StatusLabel.Text = "News Added";
    }
    else
    {

    }
```

Comment: Get the foreign key after your insert and perform an insert for each picture that is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Change the insert to something like this:

```
Insert into News
(NewsHeader, NewsContent)
OUTPUT inserted.NewsId
values
(@NewsHeader, @NewsContent)
```

And then just use cmd.ExecuteScalar() to retrieve the value provided by the output, e.g.

```
int key = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

You can then use that key to insert your associated images.

If the question pertains to the adding of Images, assuming you have it as `System.Drawing.Bitmap` or `System.Drawing.Image` in C#, you should be able to pass it to an `image` database field type by adding it as a normal parameter.